# Supporting different environments through TestFlight

Tags: swift, testflight

Maybe this question is a duplicate but I can't find an answer.

My company wants to implement 3 different environments:

- Staging: Used when developing in Xcode
- UAT: Used when we push builds to TestFlight both internal and external.
- Prod: Used when the app is on the App Store.

As far as I know:

```
#if DEBUG
```

it's not executed when a build is in TestFlight.

Is there a way to know when it is TestFlight or AppStore build?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS / appstoreconnect process for staged application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72453145/ios-appstoreconnect-process-for-staged-application)

Comment: This is a duplicate of other questions. In this case recommend upvoting the original question, and, or offer a bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: There used to be a method to differentiate between Appstore and testflight releases but apple seems to have removed it's support and it no longer works. So, as of now we can't differentiate between Appstore and testflight installs.

This was the method that used to work previously:

```
let isTestflight = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL?.path.contains("sandboxReceipt")
```

You can use the same syntax for checking if it's Testflight or Appstore using `RELEASE` keyword:

```
#if RELEASE
print("RELEASE")
#elseif DEBUG
print("DEBUG")
#endif
```

Comment: So, are you saying that #if RELEASE it's only call in the AppStore? But #If DEBUG is only in Xcode? By using the first one, are we in an in-between stage?

Comment: What do mean in-between stage? For debugging you can use `DEBUG` and set debug configs and for `RELEASE` you can set release configs that's the purpose here.

Comment: But I want to differentiate if it's TestFlight or AppStore

Comment: There used to be a method but it no longer works. So you can only distinguish between debug and release(include appstore and testflight).

Comment: Do you remember the name of the variable?